# Longest Path of directed acyclic graph with unique colours

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given a coloured DAG (with non-unique colours), a start node and an end node, find the longest path P from start to end, where no 2 vertices in P have the same colours.

I am wondering if there is a polynomial time algorithm that solves this problem, or if it is knowably NP-HARD, or in some class of non-polynomial problems. If there is not if there are any good approximation techniques or heuristic search ideas.

Comment: If it's an ID then call it an ID, why call it a weight?

Comment: I updated the question, I agree it's also not like an 'id' but in the case of graph theory I think it's not bad to clarify that the weight is not used in a traditional sense.

Comment: @ravenspoint The proper term is actually colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is NP hard.  The Hamiltonian path problem reduces to this one as follows:

Given a graph G, make a new colored graph C, such that:

- C has a unique color corresponding to each vertex in G.
- For each color, C has |G| vertices of that color.
- Partition C into |G| "columns", where each column has a vertex of each color.
- Iff s->t is a traversable edge in G, then in C, connect each node of color COLOR(s) to the node of COLOR(t) in the next column.

Now, iff G contains a Hamiltonian path, then there is a path from the first column to the last column in C, containing exactly one vertex of each color.

Comment: Isn't this a bounded maximum distance by the number of colours?

Comment: Very clever - I’m going to remember this way of transforming undirected graphs into DAGs.

Comment: @Neil yes.  The number of colors is the size of G, which must be the same as the length of any Hamiltonian path in G.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm for finding the longest path between two vertices that have unique vertex 'weights'

```
Set saved path with length zero
Put the start vertex on top of a stack.
LOOP
    IF stack empty, STOP
    Take the top vertex of the stack and add it to the visited list and the current path
    Add adjacent vertices which aren't in the visited list to the top of the stack.
    If the destination has been reached
        IF current path has all unique weighted vertices
            IF current path is longer than saved path
                Save current path to output
        Backtrack along path to vertex adjacent to vertex on top of stack, marking vertices as unvisited
Output saved path
```

Comment: Is there a time complexity analysis of this? it seems to be non-polynomial (maybe not because the acyclic graph makes the number of paths polynomial?) because it has to backtrack to consider all possible paths from start to end before it can ensure the longest path is found? It does seem like a decent approximation algorithm though where it can be run for a finite time and keep the last saved path?

Comment: You are concerned about performance?  What is the largest graph you have to deal with.  What is your time requirement for such a graph?  The 'all paths' algorithm, on which this is based, can handle a graph with 4,700 vertices and 27,000 edges in 20 secs.  Details at  https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/All-Paths#performance

Comment: I am more concerned about optimal solution than performance. But I am curious about what class of problem this falls into in theory, not just practical performance.

Comment: If you want to discuss performance on practical problems, I am here to help.  If you want a discussion of academic arcana you will need to look for someone else.

Comment: This will enumerate all paths before or in process of selecting the ultimate answer. Enumerating all paths has exponential complexity in the worst case.